# Problems connecting Cloud Run Application to Cloud SQL using Spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to connect a Spring application (using Kotlin and Gradle) to a Google Cloud SQL instance and database. I am getting the error message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: [<project-name>:europe-west1:<db-instance>] The Cloud SQL Instance does not exist or your account is not authorized to access it. Please verify the instance connection name and check the IAM permissions for project "<project-name>"
```

I have followed the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run) on how to connect carefully, but to no avail.

### Relevant files

#### src/main/resources/application.yml

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8080}

spring:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:liquibase/db.changelog.xml
    contexts: production

  cloud:
    appId: <project-id>
    gcp:
      sql:
        instance-connection-name: <instance-connection-name>
        database-name: <db-name>
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
      default_schema: <schema>
      show_sql: true
      ddl-auto: none

  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    continue-on-error: true
    initialization-mode: always
    url: jdbc:mysql:///<db-name>?cloudSqlInstance=<instance-connection-name>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=<user>&password=<password>
    username: <user>
    password: <password>

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver

  cloud:
    gcp:
      sql:
        enabled: false
```

#### build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
        id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.4.32"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.4.32"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.4.32"
}

allOpen {
    annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
    annotation("javax.persistence.Embeddable")
    annotation("javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
}

group = "com.<company>"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.5")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.6.5")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.5")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql:1.2.8.RELEASE")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.10")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10")

    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.13.2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.2.2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.2")

    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.7.Final")
    implementation("javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2")

    implementation( "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15")

    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-jvm:2.1.21")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11")

    implementation("com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.4.4")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2:2.1.210")
    runtimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.6.5")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.6.5")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
ENV USER=appuser
# <placeholder> Replace context path for your own application
ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/openjdk-17 \
    HOME=/home/$USER \
    CONTEXT_PATH=/aws-service-baseline

RUN adduser -S $USER
# <placeholder> Add additional packages for the docker container here
RUN apk add --no-cache su-exec

# <placeholder> Replace baseline.jar with your applications JAR file (defined in build.gradle.kts)
COPY Docker/runapp.sh build/libs/<application-name>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar $HOME/
RUN chmod 755 $HOME/*.sh && \
    chown -R $USER $HOME


WORKDIR /home/$USER
CMD [ "./runapp.sh"]
```

#### Docker/runapp.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# The module to start.
# <placeholder> Replace this with your own modulename (from module-info)
APP_JAR="<application-name>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
JAVA_PARAMS="-XshowSettings:vm"

echo " --- RUNNING $(basename "$0") $(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S Z") --- "
set -x

/sbin/su-exec "$USER:1000" "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" "$JAVA_PARAMS $JAVA_PARAMS_OVERRIDE" -jar -Dserver.port=$PORT "$APP_JAR"
```

### GCP details

I have made sure the SQL instances connection is added to the Cloud Run Revisions. The IAM roles for the compute service account also seem to be right. See images

IAM: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYaC5.png

Database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NErad.png

Cloud Run connection https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKTSZ.png

### Additional details

When running `./gradlew bootRun` on my local machine (with GCP credentials present), the App works properly with an SQL connection. It also works after running `./gradle bootRun` to build the JAR file and run the JAR directly. It does not work out of the box when running in Docker, but if I add the GCP credentials to the Docker container locally, it connects to the Database.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be wrong? Any help much appreciated!

I have tried connecting locally and locally in a Docker container.

Comment: Have you double check that the current Cloud Run service account is the Compute Engine default service account?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you, this was it actually! Figured it out right before you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Human error of course. The Cloud Run Service was initially configured with another Services Account, and not the default Compute Engine Service account.

[image]